# permission issue after system call - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use in my rails app a system call

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(some_path, mode: 0770)
```

where some_path is set to some (correct) path. I get in my console

```
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:242:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Users/ghome/projects/some_file (Errno::EACCES)
```

How can I correct it ?

Comment: Did you check the permissions of `/Users/ghome/projects` ?

Comment: Is the rails code being run as `ghome` or, for example, is it being run as a `passenger` or `apache` user (assuming this was in a web app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must `chmod` the write command to the directory's owner = `chmod +x /Users/ghome/projects`and then it will go fine

Answer (score 1):

You have no write permission to the folder `/Users/ghome/projects/`.

Answer (score 1):

you do not have write permissions into that directory `/Users/ghome/projects/`.[`chown`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/FileUtils/chown/class) the directory to yourself or [`chmod`](/Users/ghome/projects/) it by which you can write into it.

Comment: the `mkdir -p` (or `mkdir_p`) handles the "doesn't exist" case.